# How to get a complete hexadecimal value from blob datatype?

Tags: java, sql, hex, blob, oracle12c

I am trying to get an hexadecimal value from a BLOB column from Java using a query so:

```
SELECT RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(thumbnail, 2000,1))) thumbnail FROM thumbnails
```

if I use the next query:

```
SELECT LENGTH(thumbnail) FROM thumbnails
```

the byte length of all thumbnails are over 6000 bytes

the first query it works because I am giving it 2000 bytes because that is the size of varchar2 file type:

How can I modify the query to get all the thumbnail (all characters) and not only 2000 characters? or another way to get hexadecimal complete from a blob value?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem without using SQL, only using Java:
the query would be executed normal:

```
String query = "SELECT thumbnail FROM Thumbnails"
ResultSet rs = DBManager.getInstance().execute(query);
```

and get the value as Blob in Java:

```
Blob thumbnail;
if (rs.next()){
    thumbnail = rs.getBlob("thumbnail");
    byte[] blobBytes = thumbnail.getBytes(1, (int)thumbnail.length());
    return Hex.encodeHexString(blobBytes).toUpperCase();
}
```

very simple...